# Pesquisar trechos em string

Tags: java, android, firebase

Em uma pesquisa filtrada em java utilizando `.startWith` (query) por exemplo:

Quero pesquisar "Policia Militar" na pesquisa eu digito "Policia" e aparece policia, ok. Se eu digitar "militar", não aparece na minha pesquisa.

Como faço para pesquisar o conteúdo de toda a *string*?

Comment: Coloca seu código para podermos ajudar

Comment: Seja mais claro em sua pergunta, coloque o código ou algum exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como o próprio nome indica [`startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) diz se a `String` **começa** com determinado texto. Para saber contem o texto em qualquer lugar e não especificamente no inicio utilize [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
String query = "Policia Militar";
query.contains("Policia"); // true
query.contains("Militar"); // true
```

No entanto repare que a pesquisa tem de ser exata no que toca a maiusculas e minusculas, logo se pesquisar por `militar` não irá dar verdadeiro:

```
query.contains("militar"); // false
```

Se isto for um problema, pode alterar a logica para transformar ambos para maiúsculo ou minusculo antes da comparação, que já resolve. Essa alteração pode ser feita tanto com [`toLowerCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) como com [`toUpperCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()):

```
String pesquisa = "militar";
query.toLowerCase().contains(pesquisa.toLowerCase()); //true
```

[Veja estes exemplos no Ideone](https://ideone.com/mnTZms)

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu o problema !